# How to show two Galois groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic to each other?

Tags: representation-theory, galois-representations

This is a question about group representation. This is not my close area but I need to understand the following.

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ be the $p^n$-torsion points of $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively. Then consider the Galois groups  $G_1=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\Lambda_1)/ \mathbb{Q})$ and $G_2=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\Lambda_2)/ \mathbb{Q})$.

How to show two Galois groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic to each other ?

Does that mean the corresponding Galois representations are isomorphic also ?

Which is the easiest way ?

Comment: What do you mean by Galois Representation?  Do you have a particular representation in mind, or are you thinking categorically?

Comment: Should add:  usually the phrase $\textit {Galois Representation}$ refers to a representation of the infinite group $\text{Gal}(\overline {\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ but I don't think that's what you have in mind.

Comment: @lulu, I have edited the question.  I have asked similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365470/does-the-galois-groups-g-1-and-g-2-are-isomorphic-under-some-suitable-assum).

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by Galois Representation in this context.  Do you mean the natural map from $\text {Gal}(\overline {\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)\to \text{Aut}(E_i(p^n))$?

Comment: In any case, [here](http://algant.eu/documents/theses/oguz.pdf) is a basic reference for Galois representations attached to torsion points on elliptic curves.

Comment: @lulu, I mean something like "a representation of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ is a group homomorphism $φ: G → GL(V,F)$."  But my main question is-how to show the Galois groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic ? What process should I follow ?

Comment: I know what a group representation is.  The question is, what exactly did you mean in this context?  In a prior comment I took a guess at what you might be thinking of...was that guess accurate?

Comment: In any case, I'm not aware of universally applicable methods to compare the torsion points on two arbitrary elliptic curves.  Doesn't mean there aren't such methods, of course, just that I am not aware of them.

Comment: @lulu, yes in your comment, you considered $Gal(\bar {\mathbb{Q}} / \mathbb {Q})$, which is much close to my thinking. I am thinking about $Gal( \mathbb{Q(\Lambda)}/ \mathbb{Q})$ instead of $Gal(\bar {\mathbb{Q}}/ \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Possibly related [See this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122901/elliptic-curves-over-qq-with-isomorphic-n-torsion). Obviously this is not quite the same since you are asking for somewhat less if you only want the galois groups to be isomorphic.

Comment: @lulu, In your suggested nice article, I have also seen the Galois representation $\rho : \text{Gal}(\bar {\mathbb{Q}}/ \mathbb{Q}) \to \text{Aut}(E_i[p^n]) \simeq \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}) $, which  is an action of $\text{Gal}(\bar {\mathbb{Q}}/ \mathbb{Q})$ on the group $E_i[p^n]$. Here $G_i= \rho(\text{Gal}(\bar {\mathbb{Q}}/ \mathbb{Q}))$,in my question. However, how to compare the galois groups $G_i,~ (i=1,~2)$ in this way ?